# NodeJS server does not work when I use OIDC middleware NPM

Tags: node.js, openid-connect, okta

I am trying to set up OKTA in my NodeJS app and I am required to have my app on HTTPS server. When I use HTTPS module in my app and it works fine.
But as soon as I integrate it with OIDC middleware I start getting an error

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

any idea what could have gone wrong here or any common issue with this set up?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember something similar, related to the Root CA used for Okta Preview from a few years ago, which was trusted by browsers but not by HTTPS calls from NodeJS itself.

I understood this to be a cost saving issue in developer setups. One sign of this was that the Subject Alternative Name in certificate properties (*.oktapreview.com) did not include the precise domain name in the Okta URL.

**DEVELOPER SETUP**

I think the solution was to export the root CA from the browser, then add it to those referenced by the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable.

See the NodeJS section from about half way down my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup/) for some notes on setting this.

**PRODUCTION SETUP**

Of course you should not do this type of thing in production or pre-production systems, since production ready certificates will be trusted by NodeJS.